# How to count Database Rows over 30 Days?

Tags: php, sql

I am working on creating a dashboard for ergonomic assessments, and I am trying to get one of my cards on the dashboard to show how many tickets are currently over 30 days old. Right now it is not yielding any results over 30 days though I have set up two tickets to be older than it.

`<?php echo $db->mysqli_result(dbQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE DATE(date_opened) > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY")); ?>`

I may be using the query wrong, but this is what I have been seeing when looking at other examples of individuals trying to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: *how many tickets are currently over 30 days old*  means `DATE(date_opened) < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY`

Comment: it seems like you are doing fine... have you tried to run the query on SQL directly? if yes, then what is the error? or you are getting blank records there

Comment: @forpas - I tried that and it yielded zero results

Comment: @SayedMohdAli yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then you don't have rows over 30 days old.

Comment: You would be correct, somebody on the project team updated the dates. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)():

```
> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

Full query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE DATE(date_opened) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

I tested this and your query returns 0 rows whilst DATE_SUB returns the correct value.

Comment: That is counting tickets, but it is counting all of my tickets.

Comment: Then you have a data issue with your date_opened values. Feel free to provide a schema and a few rows of data and we can provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
WHERE date_opened < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
------------------^ note less than
```

I recommend avoiding using `DATE(date_opened)` because that prevents the use of an index.